# Blocking IP Redirect to my Blocked page

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I had a provider supplied .htaccess editor that ran from my providers site, and my control panel.  When I listed IP's to block, the method did not allow redirection to my "blocked" page ... the IP's were blocked of course ... hehe.

So, I researched and found another method to block IP's in the .htaccess file.  Now using:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^98\.137\.207\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^98\.218\.142\.121 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^99\.33\.36\.101
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blocked.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blocked.php [R]
```

My blocked visitors are redirected to the /blocked.php page where they can email to be removed from the list.

Question:
Is this less secure than completely blocking them ... can having access to the one file allow them any hacks to gain entry to other files, that would not otherwise be accessible if they were blocked completely?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, it is less secure than a full block, but you can take steps to mitigate that.

If you're blocking them in the first place, I'm guessing you either suspected them or identified them as attempting to hack your site or otherwise misbehaving. Therefore, whatever access you provide to let them request unblocking should assume they're up to no good. That means:

1. Make it a plain HTML page, not a php page, which has more potential for abuse.
2. Place the HTML page in a directory separate from your main web root so that you can tighten the rules on that directory (no script execution, no symlinks, tighter permissions, etc.).
3. If the request for unblocking is by email, just list the address or give a mailto link, don't set up a form, which is another avenue for mischief.

Comment: Up until a month or so ago the site was nothing but html from 20 years ago when it was first published.  Sooo many old forum referrers, and bandwidth theft.  I have the bad guys blocked as well as a few that may have innocently requested a non-existent page too many times.  All but my root is locked down using php requires.  The root php page simply requires the page from behind the block.  Email link is javascript driven.